# How to install something on Ubuntu core?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I have installed this version of ubuntu core: [FriendlyCore (based on ubuntu-core with Qt) | FriendlyARM WiKi](http://wiki.friendlyarm.com/wiki/index.php/Ubuntu_Core_with_Qt-Embedded)
But there is no terminal to install other things on it!
How should I install some programs on it?

Comment: On that page, it mentions using a serial connection to get a terminal.

Comment: You can read more about using Ubuntu Core at https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/

Comment: @chai; may you explain more

Comment: I found the solution here : http://superuser.com/questions/1174358/how-to-install-something-on-ubuntu-core with using ssh protocol.